# pfSense. Alias URL Table with TAR.GZ list on FTP

Tags: pfsense

In pfSense, can I create a "Table URL" alias that points to a TAR.GZ file downloadable via FTP?
Or does it necessarily have to be a full list accessible via HTTP?